# Form authentication with redirect to another internal url JQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, sap-commerce-cloud

I have this code and I need to validate the authentication and submit the form with redirect to another internal URL when I click a button called "go there".
In my code, I need the submit part. Can I find help, please?

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function(e) {

    $('#btn-login').click(function(){ 
    var errorCount = 0; 
    $('#login-wrap input').each(function(){
      if($(this).val() === '') {
        var errorMsg = 'Please fill '+ $(this).prev('label').text();
        $(this).next('.errorMessage').text(errorMsg);
        errorCount += 1;
      }
    });

    if (errorCount === 0) { 
      $('#myModal').modal('show');  
    }
    return false;
  });
  
  // Open new tab on click
  $('#btn-gothere').click(function(){
    $('#myModal').modal('hide');  
    window.open($(this).data('url'));
  });
  
});
```

Comment: Are you asking how to open the URL in the current tab instead of a new tab?

Comment: Use use HTML for that `<form target="/internal.url"><button type="submit" id="btn-gothere">Click  Here</button></form>`

Comment: @ChrisG No, I'm asking about submit and validate a form. Because my url is internal.

Comment: This doesn't make any sense, "Because my url is internal" URL is a URL it doesn't matter how the URL looks like.

Comment: `location.href = $(this).data('url')` is a way to open in same tab.

Comment: What does "I miss the submit part" mean? Are you asking how to send the login data along with the form submission?

Comment: @ChrisG I need to validate my inputs (username and password) to submit the form. If all is correct, when click button $('#btn-gothere'), i can open my intenal url.

Comment: @jcubic I meant that a url of localhost: 9002, working with hybris and its extensions.

Comment: In the `$('#btn-gothere').click(...)` handler, do `$("#login-wrap")[0].submit()`.

Comment: @ChrisG it doesn't work

Comment: That's a useless problem description. It works for me, so how exacty is it not working for you? are you getting a console error? Does the browser navigate to the upload URL at all?

Comment: @ChrisG In this case, yhe button $('#btn-gothere') don't work. https://jsfiddle.net/y8pfzh0c/1/

Comment: You misunderstood. Inside the regular button click handler, the one you have, replace `window.open($(this).data('url'));` with `$("#login-wrap")[0].submit()`. (and please don't use w3schools)

Comment: @ChrisG, it's work with 
       $("#login-wrap").submit(); thnx

Answer (score 0):

You can set a listener on your `<form>` to look for submit event.
If it is triggered then prevent it from submitting, validate your input and if they are valid submit this form manually.

Of course you don't have to look form submit event on `<form>`. You can still use your `click` event but you will have to provide `form` for submit method.

```js
// listen on form submit
$('#form').on('submit', event => {
  // prevent form from submitting
  event.preventDefault();
  
  // save target to variable (target is our form)
  const form = event.target;
  
  // check if form is valid
  if(isFormValid()) {
    // if form is valid then submit it and user will be moved to location provided in "action" parameter with all data from this form
    form.submit();
  }
});

// yes it is
const isFormValid = () => true;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="form" action="/some/url" method="POST">
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```